# Azure IoT Hub message routing

Tags: azure, iot, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send data coming in from the IoT hub into Service Bus when the routing criteria is met. For example, if temp level reaches a certain level. My device would send a JSON format "alert": true.

When I set the routing query to $body.alert = true. It does nothing and it won't route to the Service Bus for notifications.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
message.ContentType = "application/json";
message.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
```

see more details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/iot-hub-message-routing-now-with-routing-on-message-body/)